# Getting the field names of case classes defined in an object enclosed in another object

Tags: scala, reflection, inner-classes, case-class

I have two case classes defined as follows

```
object Outer {
   case class OuterCase(outerParam: Int)
   object Inner {
      case class InnerCase(innerParam: Int)
   }
}
```

and I would like to get the field names of their instances like this:

```
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ProductCompletion

object EncapsulatedCase extends App {
   val outer = Outer.OuterCase(1)
   println("outer: " + new ProductCompletion(outer).caseNames)

   val inner = Outer.Inner.InnerCase(2)
   println("inner: " + new ProductCompletion(inner).caseNames)
}
```

This works as expected for the object `outer`, but not for `inner`. Here is the output:

```
outer: List(outerParam)
inner: List()
```

The only difference I see is that class `InnerCase` is defined in an object itself defined in another object, whereas `OuterCase` is enclosed in only one object.

Why would that be a problem? Why can I get the parameter names of the `outer` but not the `inner` case object?

I observed this behavior with Scala 2.9.2.

Thank you!

### Some Additional Notes

I noticed that running the same compiled classes from the command line with `scala` or with sbt differ.

From the command line:

```
julien@minare:~/prog/testing$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.9.2 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL
julien@minare:~/prog/testing$ scala -cp target/scala-2.9.2/classes:/Users/julien/.sbt/boot/scala-2.9.2/lib/scala-library.jar:/Users/julien/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scalap/jars/scalap-2.9.2.jar:
/Users/julien/.sbt/boot/scala-2.9.2/lib/scala-compiler.jar org.example.EncapsulatedCase
outer: List(outerParam)
inner: List()
```

But with sbt:

```
> scala-version
[info] 2.9.2
> sbt-version
[info] 0.11.2
> show external-dependency-classpath
[info] ArrayBuffer(Attributed(/Users/julien/.sbt/boot/scala-2.9.2/lib/scala-library.jar), Attributed(/Users/julien/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scalap/jars/scalap-2.9.2.jar), Attributed(/Users/julien/.sbt/boot/scala-2.9.2/lib/scala-compiler.jar))
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Apr 24, 2012 9:20:21 AM
> run-main org.example.EncapsulatedCase
[info] Running org.example.EncapsulatedCase 
outer: List()
inner: List()
```

Any hint about finding out what is happening here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have scalap-2.9.2.jar, scala-library.jar, scala-dbc.jar, scala-swing.jar, and scala-compiler.jar (version 2.9.2) on the classpath in that order.

Comment: scala-db.jar and scala-swing.jar are not necessary (they come from the Eclipse Scala Library bundle)

Comment: Same behavior in  Scala 2.9.1.r0-b20110831114755

Comment: On Scala 2.9.0.1, I have `List()` for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find an explanation of what is happening, but I found a way around it using Java reflection.

**Therefore I would still very much appreciate an answer addressing `ProductCompletion`'s behaviour**.

Here is an attempt to case classes fields declared in the primary constructor. This is nothing new and not guaranteed to work. I explain below shortly why.

```
def caseNameTypeValues(a: AnyRef) = caseFields(a).map{field => (field.getName, field.getType, field.get(a))}
def caseFields(a: AnyRef) = a.getClass.getDeclaredFields.toSeq.filterNot(_.isSynthetic).take(numConstructorParams(a)).map{field =>
        field.setAccessible(true)
        field
}
def numConstructorParams(a: AnyRef) = a.getClass.getConstructors()(0).getParameterTypes.size
```

`numConstructorParams(AnyRef)` gives the number `N` of parameters to the first constructor returned by `getConstructors()`, and `caseFields(AnyRef)` returns the first `N` fields returned by `getDeclaredFields()`. `caseNameTypeValues(AnyRef)` maps those fields to their names, types and values.

WARNING: this is not guaranteed to work since the arrays returned by the `getConstructors()` and `getDeclaredFields()` methods "are not sorted and are not in any particular order" according to the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29).

If you are lucky, this gives the expected result:

```
object Outer {
   case class OuterCase(outerParam: Int)
   object Inner {
      case class InnerCase(innerParam: Int)
   }
} 

println(caseNameTypeValues(Outer.OuterCase(1)))
println(caseNameTypeValues(Outer.Inner.InnerCase(2)))
```

outputs

```
ArrayBuffer((outerParam,int,1))
ArrayBuffer((innerParam,int,2))
```